# Eloquent: Get specific data from pivot table when retrieving all

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a many to many relationship between Users & Courses with a pivot table, Users_Courses, containing an `isComplete` value, but i can't seem to retrieve the `isComplete` value without looping through every user, getting their courses and then looping over every course getting the pivot data.

All the examples i have found is to map the `isComplete` value to the course with loops, but that seems like it's awfully taxing on the program and i don't really find it appealing which is why I'm making my own question here. If there's already an answer to this that i haven't seen please link it below as i can't seem to find it.

Also, I'm using Laravel-9 and MySQL.

The data structure I'm retrieving right now looks like this:

```json
"data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "fname": "name",
            "lname": "last name",
            "email": "mail@mail.com",
            "courses": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test_course_1",
                    "description": "this is a test course for testing"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "test_course_2",
                    "description": "this is also a test course"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "test_course_3",
                    "description": "this course is a test course"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I'm searching for a way to retrieve the pivot value `isComplete` with Eloquent and getting the data with the course itself like this or something like it.

***In other words, I want to check if the user has completed the course or not through the pivot table value `isComplete` as shown in the example below.***

```json
"data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "fname": "name",
            "lname": "last name",
            "email": "mail@mail.com",
            "courses": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test_course_1",
                    "description": "this is a test course for testing",
                    "isComplete": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "test_course_2",
                    "description": "this is also a test course",
                    "isComplete": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "test_course_3",
                    "description": "this course is a test course",
                    "isComplete": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The code i have right now looks like this:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'user_courses')
            ->withPivot('isCompleted');
    }
}
```

```php
class Course extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_courses')
            ->withPivot('isCompleted');
    }
}
```

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getUsersById(int $user_id)
    {
        try {
            $users = User::where('id', $user_id)
                ->with('courses')
                ->get();

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $users
            ]);
        } catch (Throwable $th) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'data' => null,
                'message' => $th,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that it's called `isCompleted` in the code, but it's also called that in the database. It's a typing error which haven't yet been fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

**In other words, I want to check if the user has completed the course or not through the pivot table value isComplete as shown in the example below.**

Did you read about filtering using Pivot table columns in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

If you need only completed courses you can call relation as

```
$users = User::where('id', $user_id)
        ->with(['courses' => function($query) {
            $query->wherePivot('isCompleted', 1);  // use quotes if its datatype is enum in database.
        }])
        ->get();
```

Or you can make customized relations for completed, Incompleted in your Model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'user_courses')
            ->withPivot('isCompleted');
    }

    public function completedCourses()
    {
        $this->courses()->wherePivot('isCompleted', 1);
    }
    
    public function InCompleteCourses()
    {
        $this->courses()->wherePivot('isCompleted', 0);
    }
}
```

And in user controller you can call them as

```
        $users = User::where('id', $user_id)
            ->with('completedCourses')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the output to be like the JSON:

```php
$user = User::with("courses")->find(1);
$user = $user->courses->each(
  function($course) {
    $course->isComplete = $course->pivot->isComplete;
    unset($course->pivot);
  }
);
```

this line will retrieve `Courses` with an object `pivot`, which includes the columns of your pivot table.

(Example)

[image]

Comment: I am aware :) I want to retrieve all the `isComplete` values for each course the user is assigned to in the pivot table to check whether or not the user has completed the course. Is this not the correct way to do so?

Comment: Do you want to check if the user has completed all the courses, at least one course, or a specific course?

Comment: I want to check if the user has completed a specific course as shown in the second example of JSON in the question where the `isCompleted` value is retireved with Courses :)

Comment: if you want the output to be like the JSON:
`User::with("courses")->find(id);` this line will retrieve `Courses` with an object `pivot`, which includes the columns of your pivot table.

Comment: That would mean that the data from the pivot table is not directly linked as the json example but as an underlying table in the object itself, correct? How would i then go about returning the actual value in the json? I don't think I'm understanding :)

Comment: The example given also seems to not work. I've done the following: `$users = User::with('courses')->find(1)->get();` (1 being ar hardcoded value for testing) but it returns all users when it should only return one user, and it doesn't return the courses or anything from the pivot table

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it well. You have to use `->withPivot('isCompleted');` instead of `->with('isCompleted');` In The `Course` class, `users()` method

Comment: Ah yes, but even after I've changed it, it still doesn't work with your given example :(

Comment: `$users = User::with('courses')->find(1)->get();`: `find()` returns an object. So, remove `->get()`;

Comment: I am actually a 10 IQ developer.. It turns out i had added 'pivot' to the $hidden array in the Course model...

But i appreciate the time you have given this! I've learned a lot from this mistake

Comment: I get the user with the courses and then there's a nested 'pivot' object under each course :D

Comment: Like the image in the answer?

Comment: Yes exactly :) Quick top up question, is there a way to only get the `isComplete` value? I have no use for sending the user_id and course_id in the request.

Comment: You have to loop into each course and update it. I wrote an implementation in the answer section above.

Comment: Just thought i'd share what I've discovered. I'm able to use the ->select() function and then select the 'isComplete' column and retrieve it as the example json i wanted :D